# Get some alphabet characters and nothing else

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if the input is Persian and it's at least 3 characters.
When I use below regex it works. It checks if the beginning of the word is Persian, but I want it to end with Persian, too, and to contain no English alphabet and no numbers.

```
/^[ئابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهآی\s]{3,}/
```

For ensuring it ends with Persian I add `$` after `]` but I get this error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 77
>
> ```
> /^[ئابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهآی\s]${3,}/
> ```

Also, what is `\s` before the closing bracket `]`? Is it for new line?

Comment: \s means white space

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match arabic letters you can use:

```
^[\x{600}-\x{6FF}]{3,}$
```

---

```
if (preg_match('/^[\x{600}-\x{6FF}]{3,}$/u', $value)) {
    # match
} else {
    # no match
}
```

Comment: i see these, but i dont why it doesent work for me, and i get this error:  Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset. i also use meta char="utf-8"

Comment: now it's work. thank you man, and this is even better than my way. persian alphabetic have few charecter more than arabic but suport them too. thank u

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy: I have re-coded your expression using `\x` notation, please check. Also, it is OK to use literals, display issue is of no importance to regex engine.

Comment: @ stribizhev yes man thanks a lot but don't u think this regex is shorter and better?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/^[ئابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهآی\s]{3,}$/u
```

`$` is the end of line/string anchor and is not quantifiable (i.e. you cannot use a `+` or `*` or `{1,}` after it).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG9gK4/1)

As for `\s`, it just matches whitespace from this set: `[\r\n\t\f ]`.

**EDIT**: Using [Rishida Unicode Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/), I [re-wrote your expression](https://regex101.com/r/mS8tB5/2) using `\x` blocks:

```
/^[\x{626}-\x{628}\x{67E}\x{62A}-\x{62C}\x{686}\x{62D}\x{62E}\x{62F}-\x{632}\x{698}\x{633}-\x{63A}\x{641}\x{642}\x{6A9}\x{6AF}\x{644}-\x{648}\x{622}\x{6CC}]{3,}$/u
```

It does not allow spaces and looks nicer than `^[ئابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهآی]{3,}$` that [should also work](https://regex101.com/r/mS8tB5/1) (BTW, in MS Word it will look prettier :)).

Comment: it's work dude, but still have problem with space. i want space not count as word length, cuase if user enter 3 space the expersinon return true, how can i trim space from start and end of expersion and prevent from user to enter some space after each other?

Comment: Just remove it from your expression if you do not want to allow spaces to be input: `^[ئابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهآی]{3,}$` The display issue does not mean you cannot use this to validate strings. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mS8tB5/1) The regex engine knows how to read literals.

Comment: i do scaping space befor preg_match preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$user->firstname) , and i think it's not bad way